# How to give private IP access to users over SSL VPN on IBM Cloud

Tags: ibm-cloud, vpn

I have created different users on my IBM Cloud account and enabled SSL VPN Access on each of them. However, I can not figure out how to let them access the private IP address of the virtual machine on the account when they are on VPN (the owner account can do this). After applying different combinations of access groups I am stuck. Can anyone help?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed this step of providing IAM Access to the users. Check this [link](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iaas-vpn?topic=iaas-vpn-getting-started) for more information on providing the required access
**Enabling SSL VPN access**

To get started, you'll need to enable VPN access on each account that needs VPN access. To enable SSL VPN access, follow these steps:

1. Log in to the [IBM Cloud console](https://cloud.ibm.com/).
2. Click Manage > Access (IAM), and select Users.

> If you need to add a user, click Add VPN-only user or Invite users.
> For more information, see [Inviting users to an account](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-iamuserinv).

3. Select the name of the user that you want to assign SSL VPN access.
4. From the Manage User page, select the Classic Infrastructure tab and then click VPN subnets.
5. Select the Enable SSL VPN Access checkbox and click Save.

Comment: I had to disable as well the "Auto-assign" on step 5 above and assign manually the private subnet the user is going to connect to.